# How to SELECT (SQL) items only if they are in increasing order?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in SQL say like the following:

```
--------------------------
|ID | number| numberDate |
|---|-------|-------------
| 1 | 120   | 2011-01-22 |
|---|-------|------------|
| 1 | 124   | 2011-01-27 |
|---|-------|------------|
| 2 | 136   | 2011-01-20 |
|---|-------|------------|
| 2 | 135   | 2011-01-30 |
|---|-------|------------|
| 3 | 150   | 2011-01-15 |
|---|-------|------------|
| 3 | 155   | 2011-01-19 |
|---|-------|------------|
| 3 | 180   | 2011-01-23 |
--------------------------
```

I would like to select the the IDs that have an increasing number. In the example above, I would select ID 1 and ID 3 because: for ID 1 we have 120<124 and for ID 3 we have 150<155<180.

The output should be:

```
-----
|ID | 
|---|
| 1 |
|---|
| 3 |
-----
```

I cannot figure it out.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I added the third column and I put some sample output.

Comment: And what column indicates the actual order of the records?

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no sense of a next or previous row, unless you have a column that defines that ordering.  Do you have an `id` columns or creation date with the appropriate ordering?

Comment: I have a column named numberDate in which the corresponding ID put the number.

Comment: do you want both "1" or group them?

Comment: @Kira Please add that column data to your question by editing it and add the expected output based on the updated sample data.

Comment: What if your 3 / 155 was 3 / 145 ... do you want that set since 145 < 180 ? or do you want to discard it because 145 < 150 ??

Comment: I want to discard it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll do this in two steps.

```
--Step 1: Find records the violate the rule
With BadIDs AS (
    --IDs where there is another record with a matching ID and lower number, but greater date
    select t1.id
    from [table] t1
    inner join [table] t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
    where t1.number > t2.number and t1.numberDate < t2.numberDate
)
-- Step 2: All IDs not part of the first step:
select distinct ID from [table] WHERE ID NOT IN (select ID from BadIDs)
```

Unfortunately, MySql doesn't support CTEs (Common Table Expressions). Here's a version that will work with MySql:

```
select distinct ID 
from [table] 
WHERE ID NOT IN 
 (
    select t1.id
    from [table] t1
    inner join [table] t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
    where t1.number > t2.number and t1.numberDate < t2.numberDate
 )
```

Comment: I'd swear that `mysql` wasn't in the tag list when I first wrote this, but I that it is there now, and it's always part of the the revision history... so, yeah, this won't work with MySql, because MySql doesn't support CTEs. I'll update with a version that does in just a moment...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `where exists...subquery`.

this query should give you all id's have increasing number:

```
select distinct t.id from table_name t
where exists (
select t2.number 
from table_name t2 
where t2.id=t.id
and t2.number > t.number
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit to not knowing for sure if `MYSQL` will handle these analytic functions, however, I believe they should.
I test ran this on Oracle, though .. so you might need some minor tweaks ...

(the w_data view is just mimicking your data ... )
It then orders the data by two methods: by date, and by value.
It then compares those 2 orders .. if they match all the way, you're ok. If anything doesn't line up .. then the values diminished in there somewhere.

```
  with w_data as ( 
        select 1 id, 120 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-22','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual union all
        select 1 id, 124 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-27','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual union all
        select 2 id, 136 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-20','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual union all
        select 2 id, 135 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-30','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual union all
        select 3 id, 150 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-15','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual union all
        select 3 id, 155 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-19','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual union all
        select 3 id, 180 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-23','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual union all
        select 4 id, 150 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-15','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual union all
        select 4 id, 145 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-19','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual union all
        select 4 id, 180 cnumber, to_date('2011-01-23','yyyy-mm-dd') numDate from dual
        ),
     w_check as (
        select id, cnumber, numDate,
                 row_number() over (partition by id order by numDate) ordDate,
                 row_number() over (partition by id order by cnumber) ordNum,
                 count(*) over (partition by id) cnt
          from w_data
        )
  select id
    from w_check
   where ordDate = ordNum
   group by id, cnt
   having count(*) = cnt
  /
```

Results:

```
          ID  
  ---------- 
           1  
           3  

  2 rows selected.
```